# How do I compile this list of mean values into a table?

Tags: r, datatable, summary

I need to calculate the average length of stay of several years' worth of data, dependent on patient demographic (CPL status and census or discharge status). I've calculated the mean of these, with contingencies, and assigned them as values so I remember what they are. I am interested in compiling the list of values into a table so I can export the whole thing to excel.

Here's what I have:

```
#2014 average
#census#
y2014_cen_all <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2014),]$los_years)
y2014_cen_cpl <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2014 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl"),]$los_years)
y2014_cen_non <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2014 & inp$cpl_stat == "non"),]$los_years)

#discharge
y2014_dis_all <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2014 & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2014_dis_all_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2014 & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])  

y2014_dis_cpl <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2014 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl" & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2014_dis_cpl_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2014 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl" & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])  

y2014_dis_non <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2014 & inp$cpl_stat == "non" & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2014_dis_non_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2014 & inp$cpl_stat == "non" & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])  


#2015 average
#census#
y2015_cen_all <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2015),]$los_years)
y2015_cen_cpl <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2015 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl"),]$los_years)
y2015_cen_non <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2015 & inp$cpl_stat == "non"),]$los_years)

#discharge
y2015_dis_all <- mean(     inp[(inp$year == 2015 & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2015_dis_all_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2015 & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])  

y2015_dis_cpl <- mean(     inp[(inp$year == 2015 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl" & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2015_dis_cpl_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2015 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl" & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])  

y2015_dis_non <- mean(     inp[(inp$year == 2015 & inp$cpl_stat == "non" & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2015_dis_non_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2015 & inp$cpl_stat == "non" & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])  


#2016 average
#census#
y2016_cen_all <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2016),]$los_years)
y2016_cen_cpl <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2016 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl"),]$los_years)
y2016_cen_non <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2016 & inp$cpl_stat == "non"),]$los_years)

#discharge
y2016_dis_all <- mean(     inp[(inp$year == 2016 & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2016_dis_all_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2016 & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])  

y2016_dis_cpl <- mean(     inp[(inp$year == 2016 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl" & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2016_dis_cpl_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2016 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl" & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])  

y2016_dis_non <- mean(     inp[(inp$year == 2016 & inp$cpl_stat == "non" & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2016_dis_non_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2016 & inp$cpl_stat == "non" & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])  


#2017 average
#census#
y2017_cen_all <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2017),]$los_years)
y2017_cen_cpl <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2017 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl"),]$los_years)
y2017_cen_non <- mean(inp[(inp$year == 2017 & inp$cpl_stat == "non"),]$los_years)

#discharge
y2017_dis_all <- mean(     inp[(inp$year == 2017 & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2017_dis_all_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2017 & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])  

y2017_dis_cpl <- mean(     inp[(inp$year == 2017 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl" & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2017_dis_cpl_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2017 & inp$cpl_stat == "cpl" & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])  

y2017_dis_non <- mean(     inp[(inp$year == 2017 & inp$cpl_stat == "non" & inp$census_discharge == "disch"),]$los_years)
y2017_dis_non_count <- nrow(inp[inp$year == 2017 & inp$cpl_stat == "non" & inp$census_discharge == "disch",])
```

These are all stored in the environment.

How do I create a table that looks like this:

| Year | Total Average | CPL Average | Total Excluding CPL Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | avg | avg | avg |
| 2015 | avg | avg | avg |
| 2016 | avg | avg | avg |
| 2017 | avg | avg | avg |

---

### Edit

I'm using just one dataset, here is an example:
[image: example_dataset]

Here is a screenshot of the environment when I run the above code:
[image: environment_with_mean_values]

Here is output from `dput(head(inp, n = 10))`, with sensitive information removed:

```r
#> dput(head(inp, n = 10))
structure(list(unit = c("065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", 
"065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", 
"065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", 
"065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", 
"065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", 
"065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit"), 
    admission_date = structure(c(1329091200, 1349222400, 1253059200, 
    1403568000, 1419292800, 1194393600, 1265241600, 1021420800, 
    777859200, 1357603200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), discharge_date = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 
    ".", ".", ".", "."), discharge_month = c(".", ".", ".", ".", 
    ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."), disposition = c(".", ".", 
    ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."), los_days = c(1053, 
    820, 1933, 191, 9, 2612, 1792, 4614, 7433, 723), los_years = c(2.88493150684932, 
    2.24657534246575, 5.2958904109589, 0.523287671232877, 0.024657534246575, 
    7.15616438356164, 4.90958904109589, 12.641095890411, 20.3643835616438, 
    1.98082191780822), gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
    "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"), legal_status = c(21, 
    32, 32, 32, 20, 21, 32, 32, 32, 32), cpl_stat = c("non", 
    "non", "non", "non", "non", "non", "non", "non", "non", "non"
    ), prin_diag = c("Schizophrenia, Undifferentiated Type", 
    "Schizophrenia", "Schizophrenia", "Schizoaffective Disorder", 
    "Schizoaffective disorder, Bipolar type", "Schizoaffective disorder, Bipolar type", 
    "Schizophrenia, Paranoid Type", "Schizophrenia, Undifferentiated Type", 
    "Schizoaffective disorder, Bipolar type", "Schizophrenia, Paranoid Type"
    ), year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014), census_discharge = c("cen", "cen", "cen", "cen", 
    "cen", "cen", "cen", "cen", "cen", "cen"), inp_res = c("inp", 
    "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Is the data sensitive or proprietary?  If not, please provide a reproducible example ("reprex") of your datasets, by pasting the output from `dput(head(y*_cen_all, n = 10))` and `dput(head(y*_dis_all, n = 10))`.  If you can't share the data _itself_, then please give us some description of the _schema_ for each dataset.

Comment: Also, the best way to handle a situation like this — with several datasets to deal with — is to put all your datasets in a named `list`, and then do `dplyr::bind_rows(list_of_datasets, .id = "which_dataset")`.

Comment: Thanks, Greg! I have added a screenshot of an example dataset. I do only have dataset, to pull from, but all of the variables I've created are assigned names and are located in the environment. I'll attach a screenshot of that, as well.

Comment: In that case, please update your question by pasting the output from `dput(head(inp, n = 10))`.

Comment: Thanks for the reprex!  Now quick question: your intended result (table) only distinguishes between CPL ("**CPL Average**") and non-CPL ("**Total Excluding CPL Average**"), along with a grand total ("**Total Average**").  **Do you want the resulting table to also distinguish between discharge and census?**  I also have another question: when calculating `y*_dis_all`, you make sure to filter with `inp$census_discharge == "disch"`; so **why do you _not_ filter (`inp$census_discharge == "cen"`) when calculating `y*_cen_all`**?

Comment: @Greg great questions! Length of Stay (LOS) calculations should include all patients who received services in the time period of interest - in my case that is per year. Census patients are those who have received services but have not yet been discharged, and discharge patients have also received services but are not included in the patient database's census, so must be included manually. I am interested in creating a table for those discharged only, but figured if I learned how to create the table itself then I can place further restrictions and create a table for just discharges on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to keep your original dataset (`inp`), and achieve your summary by grouping and reshaping your `inp`.

## "Tidy" Table

Start by loading your resources...

```r
# Load the necessary packages...
library(dplyr)  # ...for manipulating data.


# ...
# Get your dataset: 'inp'
# ...
```

...and then apply this workflow:

```r
out <- inp %>%
  # Declutter the data.
  select(year, cpl_stat, census_discharge, los_years
    
  # Group by year...
  ) %>% group_by(year
    
  # ...and add columns with yearly aggregates (listed for every row).
  ) %>% mutate(
    avg_year = mean(los_years),
    n_year = n()
    
  # Group further by census/discharge ("cendis") status...
  ) %>% group_by(census_discharge
    
  # ...and add columns with yearly aggregates by that status (for every row).
  ) %>% mutate(
    avg_year_cendis = mean(los_years),
    n_year_cendis = n()
    
  # Group further by CPL status...
  ) %>% group_by(cpl_stat
    
  # ...and summarize with yearly aggregates for combinations of statuses.
  ) %>% summarize(
    avg_year_cendis_cpl = mean(los_years),
    n_year_cendis_cpl = n(),
    
    # Preserve the earlier groupings...
    year = first(year),
    census_discharge = first(census_discharge),
    
    # ...and their aggregates.
    avg_year = first(avg_year),
    n_year = first(n_year),
    avg_year_cendis = first(avg_year_cendis),
    n_year_cendis = first(n_year_cendis)
    
  # Reorganize the result in order of grouping.
  ) %>% select(
    year, census_discharge, cpl_stat,
    avg_year, n_year,
    avg_year_cendis, n_year_cendis,
    avg_year_cendis_cpl, n_year_cendis_cpl
  )
```

Given an `inp`ut like your example

```r
inp <- structure(
  list(
    unit = c(
      "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit",
      "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit",
      "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit",
      "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit",
      "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit", "065:Ward 65 Elder Rehab Medical Unit"
    ),
    admission_date = structure(
      c(
        1329091200, 1349222400, 1253059200, 1403568000, 1419292800,
        1194393600, 1265241600, 1021420800,  777859200, 1357603200
      ),
      tzone = "UTC",
      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
    ),
    discharge_date  = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."),
    discharge_month = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."),
    disposition     = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."),
    los_days = c(1053, 820, 1933, 191, 9, 2612, 1792, 4614, 7433, 723),
    los_years = c(
      2.88493150684932, 2.24657534246575,  5.2958904109589, 0.523287671232877, 0.024657534246575,
      7.15616438356164, 4.90958904109589, 12.641095890411, 20.3643835616438,   1.98082191780822
    ),
    gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"),
    legal_status = c(21, 32, 32, 32, 20, 21, 32, 32, 32, 32),
    cpl_stat = c("non", "non", "non", "non", "non", "non", "non", "non", "non", "non"),
    prin_diag = c(
      "Schizophrenia, Undifferentiated Type",   "Schizophrenia",
      "Schizophrenia",                          "Schizoaffective Disorder",
      "Schizoaffective disorder, Bipolar type", "Schizoaffective disorder, Bipolar type",
      "Schizophrenia, Paranoid Type",           "Schizophrenia, Undifferentiated Type",
      "Schizoaffective disorder, Bipolar type", "Schizophrenia, Paranoid Type"
    ),
    year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014),
    census_discharge = c("cen", "cen", "cen", "cen", "cen", "cen", "cen", "cen", "cen", "cen"),
    inp_res = c("inp", "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp", "inp")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -10L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

this should yield a tidy `out`put, with **one row for every combination of `year` with `census_discharge` and `cpl_stat`**.

```r
# A tibble: 1 × 9
   year census_discharge cpl_stat avg_year n_year avg_year_cendis n_year_cendis avg_year_cendis_cpl n_year_cendis_cpl
  <dbl> <chr>            <chr>       <dbl>  <int>           <dbl>         <int>               <dbl>             <int>
1  2014 cen              non          5.80     10            5.80            10                5.80                10
```

**The measures (`avg_*` and `n_*`) are listed for every "level" of grouping.**  For example, consider the `avg_*` measures:

- `avg_year` appears redundantly as the average for that recurring `year`; then
- `avg_year_cendis` appears redundantly as the average for that recurring combination of `year` and `census_discharge` status; and finally
- `avg_year_cendis_cpl` appears just once, as the average for that *unique* combination of `year` with `census_discharge` status and `cpl_stat`us.

### Note

By sheer coincidence, the measures (`avg_*` and `n_*`) are *here* the same (`5.80` and `10`) across all levels of grouping (`_year` with `_cendis` and `_cpl`).  This is simply because the sample data (`inp`) has only one grouping's worth of data: `2014` is the only `year` present, `"cen"` the only `census_discharge`, and `"non"` the only `cpl_stat`.  **With the *full* `inp` dataset, these measures will vary, as they should.**

## "Wide" Table

To achieve your desired form, with one *column* (rather than one *row*) for every combination, you must apply further steps.  First load additional resources

```r
# Load the necessary packages...
library(tidyr)    # ...for reshaping data...
library(stringr)  # ...and for manipulating strings.
```

...and then apply this workflow to reshape the data.

```r
out %>%
  # Prefix columns with '.' to avoid clashes.
  rename_with(~paste0(".", .)
  
  # Pivot to get a measure column for every CPL status.
  ) %>% pivot_wider(
    # Prefix the columns with the CPL status...
    names_from = .cpl_stat,
    # ...and append the aggregate's label: '*' from '*_year_cendis_cpl'.
    names_glue = "{.cpl_stat}_{
      stringr::str_extract(.value,
        pattern = '^\\\\.?(.*?)(?:_year_cendis_cpl|$)',
        group = 1
      )
    }",
    
    # Target all aggregates of the form '*_year_cendis_cpl'.
    values_from = ends_with("_year_cendis_cpl"),
    
    # Represent any missing values as "blanks" (NAs).
    values_fill = NA
    
  # Pivot to get a measure column for every census/discharge status.
  ) %>% pivot_wider(
    # Prefix the columns with the census/discharge status...
    names_from = .census_discharge,
    # ...and append either the new measure's name or the aggregate's label.
    names_glue = "{
      # Get only the first three letters: 'cen' and 'dis'
      stringr::str_sub(.census_discharge, end = 3)
    }{
      # Label with '_all' where applicable.
      ifelse(str_starts(.value, '\\\\.'), '_all', '')
    }_{
      stringr::str_extract(.value,
        pattern = '^\\\\.?(.*?)(?:_year_cendis|$)',
        group = 1
      )
    }",
    
    # Target all new measures and all aggregates of the form '*_year_cendis'.
    values_from = !starts_with(".") | ends_with("_year_cendis"),
    
    # Represent any missing values as "blanks" (NAs).
    values_fill = NA
    
  # Clean up the names of columns left unpivoted.
  ) %>% rename_with(.cols = starts_with("."), ~paste0(
    # Prepend "total_" where appropriate.
    ifelse(str_ends(., "_year"), "total_", ""),
    str_extract(.,
      # Extract any aggregate's label: '*' from '.*_year'.
      pattern = '^\\.?(.*?)(?:_year|$)',
      group = 1
    )
    
  # Sort the measures alphabetically.
  )) %>% select(
    year, starts_with("total"), sort(names(.))
  )
```

Given an `inp` as before, this should yield the following output:

```r
# A tibble: 1 × 7
   year total_avg total_n cen_all_avg cen_all_n cen_non_avg cen_non_n
  <dbl>     <dbl>   <int>       <dbl>     <int>       <dbl>     <int>
1  2014      5.80      10        5.80        10        5.80        10
```

**Notice how a separate measure column appears for every combination of `census_discharge` status and `cpl_stat`us.**  For example, the `*_avg` is labeled `cen_non_avg` for census patients that are non-CPL.  Also `*_all_avg` is used to label the total across all CPL statuses.

Finally, notice how the `total_*` columns describe the measures across all statuses for the entire year.

### Note

**This should work regardless of how many measures you introduce, so long as you label each measure properly.**  If you want to introduce standard deviation via `sd()`, you would do so by adding `sd_year = sd(los_years)` right under `avg_year = mean(los_years)` in the first workflow; and so on for `sd_year_cendis` and `sd_year_cendis_cpl`.

**Now you can expect the result to expand "wider" when the data is populated with a broader selection of statuses: your *full* `inp` dataset.**  With the full dataset, we would expect to see more columns, like `dis_cpl_avg`:

```r
# A tibble: n × 15
   year total_avg total_n cen_all_avg cen_all_n cen_cpl_avg cen_cpl_n cen_non_avg cen_non_n dis_all_avg dis_all_n dis_cpl_avg dis_cpl_n dis_non_avg dis_non_n
  <dbl>     <dbl>   <int>       <dbl>     <int>       <dbl>     <int>       <dbl>     <int>       <dbl>     <int>       <dbl>     <int>       <dbl>     <int>
```

Obviously, you can reduce this to only the averages

```r
# A tibble: n × 8
   year total_avg cen_all_avg cen_cpl_avg cen_non_avg dis_all_avg dis_cpl_avg dis_non_avg
  <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
```

by simply omitting the `n_* = ...` lines from the very first workflow.  You can also do the same at the end, with something like `... %>% select(!ends_with("_n"))`.  **I'd recommend excluding measures only at the end, so you don't lose any information: you can pick and choose exactly what you want.**

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!!! I will try this and modify as soon as I get back to work in the morning. Thank you again!!!